# Laravel Nginx Every Second Request Handle

Tags: laravel, nginx, post, request, mariadb

i want to ask about the request handle

The case is, if server receive the same post request or the same key parameter, the request is on hold first or stored until there are no more requests for 5 seconds or a certain condition. and after that the request is processed to the database

So from the client site send post every second, but server don't need to process it to the database every second, just the most recent request

Has anyone ever known about such needs, using what methods, maybe what packages or tools are needed?
I use `laravel, nginx, mariadb`

thank you,

Comment: you want to throttle a request end point? or just the result of what the end point does?

Comment: i think just the result of what the end point does.
because, just some parameter in the last request thats what i need to store into database @lagbox

Comment: maybe any suggestion? @lagbox

Comment: you could set a key in the cache with a timestamp of the last time this end point was hit ... and only if that timestamp is outside your threshold actually perform the action, perhaps ... if you are using Redis laravel has a rate limiting/throttle mechanism to use with it

Comment: ooh okay great. i should more explore Redis then. thanks @lagbox

Comment: hi @lagbox, sorry mention again
maybe you any experience in Laravel/Queue, please help me with answer this question. thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63701669/laravel-7-queue-delete-specific-job