# Laravel 7 Queue delete() specific job

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-queue

I'm working on Laravel/Cache and Laravel/Queue. i have function that `dispatch()` Queue job
`UpdateTimeImpJob::dispatch($data)->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10));`

but in some condition, before **10 seconds** after that job called i need to delete that specific Queue job. without delete any other Queue job

How to delete that specific Queue job?

this is my function @mrhn

```
public function sendTimeImpressions(Request $request) {

    $id = $request->input('IdImpLog');

    Cache::put('cacheTimeImpLogId-'.$id, 'cacheTimeImpLogId', 15);

    $data = $request->all();
    $data['date'] = Carbon::now()->format('H:i:s');
    $data['dates'] = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(4)->format('H:i:s');
    UpdateTimeImpJob::dispatch($data)->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(2));

    return response()->json([
        'status'=>true,
        'message'=>'Update Time Impressions Success'
    ]);
}
```

my work case is from client side send post request every second, let say its 10 seconds = 10 request. but i just need to process last 10th request to process it to database

so, my logic is. i create a cache for save the data. and call a queue job. if request just send 1 time. so queque job is running and process to database
 when req send 2 times or more, just the last request need to process
 so, the queue job has been called, need to delete queue job before it.

sorry for my bad english. please help, thanks

Comment: What is the condition that want you to delete the job

Comment: when that job called again with same user or same key @mrhn 
called again before 10 second or before that job processed

Comment: Can i see the whole code how you dispatch? atm i do not know what a key is etc.

Comment: why do you need to delete a queue job before it is ran?

Comment: What is the logic behind that cache and IdTmpLog, how can you check if a new job has been queued?

Comment: @lagbox this is my continued work from this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681173/laravel-nginx-every-second-request-handle?noredirect=1#comment112610131_63681173

Comment: @mrhn explained on question. already edited

Comment: Will the to requests you send have the same id? Im trying to fish out, how is the correlation between the two requests and right now information is sparse and the solution seems weird tbh.

Comment: yes this is the same id `$id = $request->input('IdImpLog');`  yeah maybe its weird solution, but just this is what i got in my head after 1 day explore in laravel cache & queue. maybe any suggest another solution for my case, im happy to know. @mrhn